# ECSlidingViewController hides when device Orientation chages to Landscape

Tags: ios, landscape, sidebar, orientation-changes, ecslidingviewcontroller

I am using ECSlidingViewController to reveal the side bar menu in my app.

> Its working fine but when the side bar appears on screen and i
>   changed the 
>       orientation of device to landscape, the side bar automatically get hides without giving any kind of notification.

Can someone suggest the solution so that when i change the orientation of device to landscape then side bar remain on screen and do not get hides. *Remember my app do not supports Landscape mode. It is only in portrait.*

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully added ECSSlidingViewController in my project using this tutorial and its working you should have tried this tutorial

```
http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/ECSlidingViewController/1.3.1/
```

hope it helps